# UK: is it legal to display a flag in front of a store?

Tags: united-kingdom, protest

Country: United Kingdom

Is it legal to:

1. leave a free standing flag of a country (Russia) close to an entrance of a store?
2. leave free standing flags:

- of a country (Russia)
- with logo/name of a store

close to an entrance of the said store?

3. leave free standing flags:

- of a country (Russia)
- with logo/name of a store
- of a president of a foreign country (Vladimir Putin)

close to an entrance of the said store?

Note that this is someone else's store. One of many belonging to an international company. This is meant as a protest.

Comment: This sounds like legal advice for an ongoing situation.

Comment: @JoeW, what do you mean?

Comment: Legal or not doesn't really matter, because it won't stay there for long. If you are the store owner, you will also have problems with your insurance. Like they won't pay for broken windows, because you actively invited such damage.

Comment: @Joe W This is not a request for specific legal advice as Law.SE policy defines that. It should not be closed on that basis. If so closed, I will vote to reopen.

Comment: @gnasher729 can you cite any legal basis on which such insurance might decline payment?

Comment: What I mean is this appears (to me at least) to be asking for legal advice which is off topic here.

Comment: @gnasher729 I am not sure placing a Russian flag outside your business is actively asking for people to break your windows and do other forms of damage. Sure people will object to the flag but that isn't asking for them to damage things as a response.

Comment: @David, would you try it? Right now I would say the reaction will be worse than for a sign "No blacks allowed".

Comment: @Joe W Our standard is that asking "What does the law permit" or "What does the law require" do not count as asking for legal advice, while asking "What should i do?" often does count.  See https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1185/excessive-use-of-specific-legal-advice-closure-reason on law.meta

Comment: @gnasher729  Posting a Russian flag outside one's shop might well be unwise, and I would not do it because I personally don't want to send that message.  But her on law.se we are generally concerned with what is legal, not what is wise. In an insurance co legally allowed to decline payment of claims for political vandalism because it was p[rovoked by an unpopular attitude? I would hope not. In the US *Cantwell v Connecticut* was supposed to end the "heckler's veto", that is the suppression of expression because those whop dislike it might be violent.

Comment: OP - can you cite a reputable source for this, please. Flying a flag in-and-of-itself is not necessarily unlawful, but the devil may be in the detail.

Answer (score 4):

**Is it illegal to display a flag in front of a store?**

*Maybe* - not because it's a flag but because it *could be* an unlawful obstruction of the highway (which includes the pavement) contrary to [section 137(1)](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1980/66/section/137?timeline=false) of the Highways Act 1980:

> If a person, without lawful authority or excuse, in any way wilfully obstructs the free passage along a highway he is guilty of an offence and liable to a fine not exceeding level 3 on the standard scale. ([i.e. £1,000](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2020/17/section/122?timeline=false))

Many shops fall foul of this if they don't have a licence, especially with 'A' boards and goods displayed for sale.

Answer (score -3):

> Critical piece of information: this is someone else's store. One of many belonging to an international franchise. This is meant as a protest.

If the result of your 'protest' (intent) is to encourage others to commit an act of violence towards a third party, then the possibility exists that you may be considered an **accomplice** to that action.

The simple placement of the Russian flag, Putins picture with the logo/name of a store is in itsself not an expression of protest.

**If**, however, the result of this placement leads to others being provoked to cause damage to the store, then a judge **could** come to the conclusion that that the main purpose of the placement was to bring about this violence.

With an added sign: 'Boycott because ....', then the intension is clearer.

Should, however, this store be one of those that **cannot** withdraw from Russia (as many cannot since they are run by franchise partners) then other problems could arise for which the person who called for the boycott could be held liable.

Comment: At what point does OP give any indication that their intent is to provoke violence? Protests need not be violent. One could equally argue that it's a call for people to boycott (or, with some reading between the lines, for the government to sanction such businesses; I'm assuming such a company would one of the ones still doing business in Russia post sanctions, something some businesses have caught flack for doing).

Comment: @sharur The OP didn't, that is why the answer started with the word '**If**'.

Comment: That is making a big assumption from the question and it would be much more likely that they are just showing support. I think it would be very hard if not impossible to prove that they intended to provoke violence.

Comment: @JoeW Really? Peaple can be called to account even for unintentional damage ([Ignorantia juris non excusat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ignorantia_juris_non_excusat)). That is why one should think things thoroughly beforehand. And yes, it **should** be difficult to prove. But judges have experience with these things and it is they that make that final determination.

Comment: Sure but that doesn't mean it will be easy to prove that they intended to provoke people to commit violence and make them an accomplice to that violence. Just because people commit violence doesn't mean that it will be easy to make a claim and prove that someone else provoked them to do violence against their own property.